# spacy size reduction to use only phrasematcher

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, spacy

I'm using Spacy in a python project and found that my Docker image is pretty big. A previous led me to find out that just the Spacy installation itself (in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy) accounts for 268MB. I am only using

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
```

this part. Is there a way I can use only phrasematcher part of the library so as to reduce the size?

Thanks

Comment: Not easily at the moment – but we're working on the package size! See here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3258